# Why test assemblies are not filtering in VSTS azure build pipeline despite putting test assembly patterns?

Tags: unit-testing, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vstest.console.exe

Here is my test assembly patterns (configuration)

```
**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
!**\obj\**  
!**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*Integration*
```

After triggering build, here is the log where integration test assembly is also there (this file must be filtered and should be here)

```
2019-04-23T13:10:33.6689787Z C:\VSTSAgent\A1\_work\1\s\myapp\myapp.Services.Test\bin\Release\myapp.Services.Test.dll
2019-04-23T13:10:33.6690018Z C:\VSTSAgent\A1\_work\1\s\myapp\myapp.Services.Integration.Test\bin\Release\myapp.Services.Integration.Test.dll
```

Becuase of this integration test cases are also  running and I want to run only unit test cases.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution, here is my latest configuration for the same which working absolutely as expected now.

```
**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
!**\obj\**
!**\myapp\*Integration*\**  
!**\*Microsoft.Owin.Testing.dll*
!**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*Integration.Test*.dll
!**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform*
!**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*MSTest*    
!**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*Microsoft.Owin.Testing.dll*
!**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll*
```

If you notice the line which says that exclude path which contains this pattern;

```
!**\myapp\*Integration*\**
```

and below pattern matches and will not be included in the result.

```
2019-04-23T13:10:33.6690018Z C:\VSTSAgent\A1\_work\1\s\myapp\myapp.Services.Integration.Test\bin\Release\myapp.Services.Integration.Test.dll
```